# Push SMS Notifications Mobilefirst

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying push SMS notifications using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation. I've read docs [Doc1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_sms_settings_put.html) and [Doc2](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/) but i don't understand how to define the url : `https://example.com:443/imfpush/v1/apps/myapp/settings/smsConf`

1. what's `example.com` my server is a local address 192.168.xxx.xxx
2. Do I call the url directly from client using SDK ?

Also I've see JSON data below :

```
{
"host": "2by0.com",
"name": "dummy",
"port": "80",
"programName": "gateway/add.php",
"parameters": [{
    "name": "xmlHttp",
    "value": "false",
    "encode": "true"
}, {
    "name": "httpsEnabled",
    "value": "false",
    "encode": "true"
}]
```

}

3. Where I'd add it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. what's example.com my server is a local address 192.168.xxx.xxx

   Replace "https://example.com:443" with your local server's details. For example, http://192.168.xxx.xxx:9080"
2. Do I call the url directly from client using SDK ?

   No, this is a REST API for the Push service. You should call this from a REST client such as curl or Postman. The purpose of the call is to create or update the SMS configuration in the MFP server.

Comment: So how can from a client tell to server to push notifications to another client ?

Comment: Client does not tell the server to push. An administrator will be doing that. They will use the appropriate REST API call to dispatch the SMS notification. Details here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_message_post.html

Comment: An administrator ? you mean a real person ? imagine that 100 clients send their phone numbers to server at the same time and expect receive pin code to active account. so an admin must handle everything ?